# UpdatePanel buttons fires onclick_event once only

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

Here Is The Code, I'll Explain it better at the end of the post

```
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <div id="infoCli" class="well" style="height: auto; width: auto;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cdCli" Enabled="False">Código</asp:Label>

                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cdCli" Width="40px" ReadOnly="True" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style39">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nmFantasia">Nome Fantasia</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNmFantasia" ControlToValidate="nmFantasia" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nmFantasia" Width="368px" MaxLength="30" TabIndex="1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nmCli">Razão Social</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNmCli" ControlToValidate="nmCli" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nmCli" Width="589px" TabIndex="2" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style42">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tpCli">Tipo de Cliente</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="tpCli" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="145px" TabIndex="3" Enabled="False">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Somente Consulta</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Eventual</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">C/ Contrato</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style54">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrCGC">CNPJ</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrCGC" Width="138px" TabIndex="4" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style69">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrCPF">CPF</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrCPF" Width="110px" TabIndex="5" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style43">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrCGF">CGF</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNmCGF" ControlToValidate="nrCGF" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrCGF" Width="134px" TabIndex="6" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style32">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1" TabIndex="7">Isento
                    <br />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                            </asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style56">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="inscMun">Insc. Mun</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvInscMun" ControlToValidate="inscMun" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="inscMun" Width="106px" TabIndex="8" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style55">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrCEI">CEI</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNmCEI" ControlToValidate="nrCEI" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrCEI" Width="133px" TabIndex="9" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style66">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrCep">CEP</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNmCep" ControlToValidate="nrCep" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ToolTip="A Consulta ao CEP só será realizada caso esteja conectado à internet" ID="nrCep" onblur="Javascript:atualizacep(this.value)" Width="98px" TabIndex="10" data-mask="99999-999" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsEnder">Endereço</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvDsEnder" ControlToValidate="dsEnder" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsEnder" Width="377px" TabIndex="11" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style46">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrEnder">Número</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNrEnder" ControlToValidate="nrEnder" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrEnder" Width="46px" TabIndex="12" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style68">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsBairro">Bairro</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvDsBairro" ControlToValidate="dsBairro" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsBairro" Width="196px" TabIndex="13" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style25">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="compEnder">Complemento</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvCompEnder" ControlToValidate="compEnder" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="compEnder" Width="141px" TabIndex="14" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style43">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsCid">Cidade</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvDsCid" ControlToValidate="dsCid" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsCid" Width="414px" TabIndex="15" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style51">&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cdUF">UF</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCdUF" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cdUF" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cdUF" Width="34px" TabIndex="166" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style48">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="foCli">Telefone</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFoCli" runat="server" ControlToValidate="foCli" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="foCli" Width="122px" TabIndex="17" />
                        </td>

                        <td class="auto-style19">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrFax">Fax</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvNrFax" ControlToValidate="nrFax" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrFax" Width="126px" TabIndex="18" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style57">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cdIBGE" Width="133px">Cód. Cidade IBGE</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvCdIBGE" ControlToValidate="cdIBGE" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cdIBGE" Width="113px" TabIndex="19" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style52">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cdNatOpe" Width="170px">Natureza da Operação</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvCdNatOpe" ControlToValidate="cdNatOpe" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cdNatOpe" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="404px" TabIndex="20">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">(escolha uma opção):</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Tributação No Município</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Tributação Fora do Município</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Isenção</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Imune</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Exigibilidade Suspensa por Decisão Judicial</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="6">Exigibilidade Suspensa por Procedimento Administrativo</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label for="CheckBox2">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" TabIndex="22" />
                                    Simples Nacional
                                </label>

                                <label for="CheckBox3">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                                    Inadiplente
                                </label>

                                <label for="CheckBox4">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" TabIndex="23" />
                                    Incentivador Cultural
                                </label>

                                <label for="CheckBox5">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" TabIndex="24" />
                                    Inativo
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                        <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="btnCons" runat="server" Text="Consultar" OnClick="Consultar" CausesValidation="false" />
                        <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="btnInse" runat="server" Text="Inserir" OnClick="Inserir" CausesValidation="false" />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="Consultar" CausesValidation="false" >Consultar</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--DIV - WELL--%>

            <br />


            <div id="endCob" class="well" style="height: auto; width: auto;">
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <label for="CheckBox7" class="checkbox-inline">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkEndeCob" OnClick="Javascript:checkEndCob()" runat="server" TabIndex="25" />
                        Endereço do cliente é o mesmo que o Endereço de Cobrança
                    </label>
                </div>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style28">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrCepCob">CEP</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrCepCob" onblur="Javascript:atualizacep(this.value)" Width="98px" TabIndex="26" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style29">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsEnderCob">Endereço</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsEnderCob" Width="373px" TabIndex="27" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style40">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrEnderCob">Número</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrEnderCob" Width="38px" TabIndex="28" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style31">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsBairroCob">Bairro</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsBairroCob" Width="179px" TabIndex="29" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style25">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="compEnderCob">Complemento</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="compEnderCob" Width="194px" TabIndex="30" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style23">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsCidCob">Cidade</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsCidCob" Width="252px" TabIndex="31" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style27">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cdUFCob">UF</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cdUFCob" Width="33px" TabIndex="32" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="foCliCob">Telefone</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="foCliCob" Width="108px" TabIndex="33" />
                        </td>

                        <td class="auto-style19">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nrFaxCob">Fax</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="nrFaxCob" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nrFaxCob" Width="113px" TabIndex="34" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <br />

            <div id="contatoCli" class="well" style="height: auto; width: auto;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style70">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nmContat1">Comercial</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="nmContat1" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nmContat1" Width="396px" TabIndex="35" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style72">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="foneCont1">Telefone</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="foneCont1" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="foneCont1" Width="122px" TabIndex="36" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style62">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsEmail1" Width="46px">E-Mail</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsEmail1" Width="343px" TabIndex="37" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style71">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nmContat2">Financeiro</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="nmContat2" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nmContat2" Width="396px" TabIndex="38" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style73">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="foneCont2">Telefone</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="foneCont2" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="foneCont2" Width="122px" TabIndex="39" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style7">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsEmail2">E-Mail</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="dsEmail2" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsEmail2" Width="343px" TabIndex="40" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style71">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nmContat3">Operacional</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="nmContat3" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nmContat3" Width="396px" TabIndex="41" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style73">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="foneCont3" Width="66px">Telefone</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="foneCont3" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="foneCont3" Width="122px" TabIndex="42" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style7">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsEmail3">E-Mail</asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsEmail3" Width="343px" TabIndex="43" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style71">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="nmContat4">Expedição</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="nmContat4" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nmContat4" Width="396px" TabIndex="44" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style73">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="foneCont4">Telefone</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="foneCont4" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="foneCont4" Width="122px" TabIndex="45" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style7">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dsEmail4">E-Mail</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="dsEmail4" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="*" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dsEmail4" Width="343px" TabIndex="46" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCons" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, Here is the problem, I have a MasterPage which has the Header and the Footer of the page, and my children page is just the content, so, in this case, this form.
When I First click the button, it will work as planned, it will go on the database retrive my data and move to the textboxes ( texbox.Text = value; ).
But when I change the values, to do a second search the OnClick_Event its not fired, I have a breakpoint in the method so I can see it doesn't get there.
Also, with FireBug on I can see that when I click the button for the first time I get a "Refference Error: MyMethod is Not Defined" but it still brings my data and enters the method.
And when I click it for the second time I get the same Refference Error and I get a

"Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404"

as well

I'm really new at ASP.NET, I Have an understaining at JSF, But, this had to be done at ASP.NET Webforms

Thanks,

Gabriel

Comment: Do you have `<form runat="server">` in your markup surrounding any ASP.NET controls (usually would be in master page)? You aren't tampering with the form action? Other potential problem is that your UpdatePanel(s) is set to conditional and you are not updating any or all update panels where controls have changed.

Comment: Hi there, 1st of all, thanks for the reply :D

2) Yes, I do have the form tag, with the runat="server"

3)Correct me if I understood it wrong but, the button should not behave as submit? I've changed that so now my button is like this

'code'<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="btnCons" runat="server" Text="Consultar" OnClick="Consultar" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />

3) Yes, changed the conditional thing, 

Still not working :(

Comment: by the way, it doesn't show the "Refference Error: MyMethod is Not Defined" anymore, neither time i click it, first or second time

Comment: Does your code work if you disable AJAX?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but, do you mean to disable Ajax functionalities on the button? I've searched it on google, but, cant find how to, all results are on how to disable button during ajax is being called

Answer (score 0):

So, Sorry!! haha I feel so dumb for not noticing that earlier!!!

In the Reference Error (JS) it said /MyPage.aspx/MyMethod, but, for some reason i forgot that MyPage.aspx is inside a folder, I still don't quite understand why the second time it "forgot" the page directory, but, I took it of the folder and put it in the project main folder, and it fixed